# How to get all field names and data types from a MongoDB instance

Tags: mongodb, datatable

I have a mongo db instance with a bunch of collections. I need to create an Excel where one column is the path to the field, and the second one is the type this keys has.

For instance, if this is my item:

```
{
   _id: ObjectId("697a6s98689asdfd89s"),
   name: "matias",
   status: {
       enabled: true,
       role: "developer"
   }
}
```

Then I want to get this :

| Field | Type |
| --- | --- |
| _id | ObjectID |
| name | string |
| status | Object |
| status.enabled | boolean |
| status.role | string |

Obviously this can be done through code, but is there any way to do this using the mongo shell to perform a query ? Or maybe get the json out from the shell and use jq/bash to perform the printing of the table?

Note: This is adapted from another answer, but it does not work, but gets there really close.

```
jq -r '. as $root |
       path(..) | . as $path |
       $root | getpath($path) as $value |
       select($value | scalars) |
       ([$path[] | @json] | join(".")) + " = " + (($value|type) | (@json|type))
    '  < item.json
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I ended up this tool: https://github.com/variety/variety
Easy to download and use and does exactly what I needed.